# Including pictures in our Newsletter

Tags: civimail, html, newsletter

How can I include pictures in the Newsletter created with Civicrm ?
Using the "Image" Button in Civicrm's HTML editor, the pictures appear in the newsletter template as well as in the "preview as HTML" window, but in both test e-mail and the actual e-mail they only appear as a frame with a torn sheet of paper in the top left corner. How can I solve this problem ?

edit:
https://civicrm.lesewelt-ortenau.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/IMG_2143%282%29.JPG

I tried opening the URL to one of the pictures at home yesterday but could not open itwhereas it works from the pcs in our office. I assume the problem is one of the two mentioned by user Fabian. However i don't know how to proceed now, having close to no experience with servers etc.

Civicrm ver.4.6.21 // Drupal

Comment: any chance you could share the URL for one of the pictures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Felix and welcome to CiviCRM Stack Exchange.

Your problem could have a number of reasons, e.g. the following:

- your server does not allow access via http for anonymous users (could
  be protected by htaccess, a vpn...)
- you do not have a ssl certificate or it is self-signed

If that is not the reason please try to provide some more information such as:

- are images not displayed for all recipients or only certain ones?
- does it happen with all mail clients/services or only certain ones
- ...

Comment: The problem was an expiered SSL-certifcate for the domain.....purchasing a new one fixed the issue.
Thanks for the quick help!